# Символьные константы строк C-style в C++

Tags: c++

Давно хотел понять, почему символьные константы строк работают следующим образом. Сравним их с массивом char. Ниже два фрагмента кода.

### С массивом char:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        char myName[] = "John";
        std::cout << myName;

        return 0;
    }
```

### С символьной константой:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        const char *myName = "John";
        std::cout << myName;

        return 0;
    }
```

Хотя обе эти программы работают и выдают одинаковые результаты, выделение
памяти в них выполняется по-разному.

В первом случае в программе выделяется память для фиксированного массива
длиной 5 и инициализируется эта память строкой John\0. Поскольку память была
специально выделена для массива, то мы можем изменять её содержимое. Сам
массив рассматривается как обычная локальная переменная, поэтому, когда он
выходит из области видимости, память, используемая им, освобождается для
других объектов.

Что происходит в случае с символьной константой? Компилятор помещает строку
John\0 в память типа read-only (только чтение), а затем создает указатель, который
указывает на эту строку. Несколько строковых литералов с одним и тем же
содержимым могут указывать на один и тот же адрес. Поскольку эта память
доступна только для чтения, а также потому, что внесение изменений в строковый
литерал может повлиять на дальнейшее его использование, лучше всего
перестраховаться, объявив строку константой (типа const). Также, поскольку строки,
объявленные таким образом, существуют на протяжении всей жизни программы
(они имеют статическую продолжительность, а не автоматическую, как
большинство других локально определенных литералов), нам не нужно беспокоиться о проблемах, связанных с областью видимости. Поэтому следующее в
порядке вещей:

```
    const char* getName()
    {
        return "John";
    }
```

В фрагменте, приведенном выше, функция getName() возвращает указатель на
строку C-style John. Всё хорошо, так как John не выходит из области видимости,
когда getName() завершает свое выполнение, поэтому вызывающий объект все
равно имеет доступ к строке.

И собственно сами вопросы. Можете объяснить, зачем для символьной константы сделали такие дополнения/ограничения? Почему компилятор помещает её в read-only память? Почему вместо

```
    const char *myName = "John";
```

нельзя объявить следующее (начиная с какой-то версии C++)?

```
    char *myName = "John";
```

Почему символьная константа строки имеет статическую продолжительность жизни?

Comment: *`"Почему символьная константа строки имеет статическую продолжительность жизни?"`* -- вероятно для единообразного представления как коротких, так и длинных констант. Понятно, что "константу" `"John"` можно положить в стек парой машинных инструкций (или одной, как 64-бит число, если не экономить память).  А вот длинные константы (даже тот текст, которым инициализируется массив) придется создавать в процессе компиляции и сохранять в секции для rodata (по сути, так глобальные переменные (конечно, сами они размещаются в другой секции), только без имен)

Comment: *`'Почему вместо

    const char *myName = "John";

нельзя объявить следующее (начиная с какой-то версии C++)?

    char *myName = "John";'`* -- это чтобы неумелые ручки делали меньше ошибок времени исполнения (segfaults)

Answer (score 4):

Если верить
[Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)),
то «*литерал* — это специальная нотация для представления
фиксированных значений в исходном коде». В отличие от литералов,
*переменные* или *константы* — это символы, которые могут
принимать одно значение из некоторого класса фиксированных
значений. То есть литералы по своей природе не предназначены для
какого-либо изменения, они сами должны представлять некоторую
фиксированную величину.

То что вы называете «символьной константой строки» на самом деле
называется *строковым литералом* (англ. *string literal*):

```c
char *s = "string"; // "string" — это строковой литерал,
                    // s — это переменная типа указателя
                    // на char, которая хранит адрес
                    // строкого литерала "string"
char x[] = "string"; // "string" — это снова строковой литерал,
                     // x — это переменная типа массива char,
                     // которая хранит значения
                     // ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'].
```

Изменить строковой литерал значило бы то же самое, что изменить
литералы `42`, `3.14f` или `'a'`.

#### «Зачем для символьной константы сделали такие дополнения/ограничения?»

1. Требования неизменяемость строкого литерала позволяет хранить
   строковые литералы пересекающимися в памяти и не хранить
   дублирующиеся литералы дважды:

   ```c
   const char *a = "string";
   const char *b = "string";
   const char *c = "longer string";
   ```

   Строковых литералов в примере выше три, но т.к. они неизменямые
   мы можем хранить их в памяти как один строковой литерал, причем
   первый и второй строковые литералы *могут* храниться как часть
   третьего.

   *Нечто похожее можно видеть в Java с его String Pool, причем
   строки в Java также являются неизменяемыми.*
2. Требование статической продолжительности хранения: во-первых,
   позволяет не пересоздавать строковые литералы каждый раз;
   во-вторых, позволяет возвращать строковой литерал из функции
   также как и обычный литерал:

   ```c
   int return_literal(void) {
       return 42;
   }

   char *return_string_literal(void) {
       return "sample";
   }
   ```

   Этот прием применяется довольно часто, например в следующем
   сценарии:

   ```c
    enum PIC_Port {
        PIC_MASTER_CMD_PORT  = 0x20,
        PIC_MASTER_DATA_PORT = 0x21,
        PIC_SLAVE_CMD_PORT   = 0xA0,
        PIC_SLAVE_DATA_PORT  = 0xA1
    };

    char *stringify_pic_port(const enum PIC_Port p) {
        switch (p) {
            case PIC_MASTER_CMD_PORT:
                return "PIC_MASTER_CMD_PORT";
            case PIC_MASTER_DATA_PORT:
                return "PIC_MASTER_DATA_PORT";
            case PIC_SLAVE_CMD_PORT:
                return "PIC_SLAVE_CMD_PORT";
            case PIC_SLAVE_DATA_PORT:
                return "PIC_SLAVE_DATA_PORT";
        }

        assert(false);
        return "";
    }
   ```

#### «Почему компилятор помещает её в read-only память?»

Компилятор не обязан помещать строковые литералы в read-only
секцию кода. Вообще говоря, понятие секцией кода — это понятие
формата исполняемого файла, на уровне языка такого понятия не
существует.

В случае, если у компилятора есть возможность поместить строковой
литерал в секцию только-для-чтения, у него есть как миниум
следующие причины сделать это:

1. Это семантически корректно, так как строковые литералы и
   являются неизменяемыми.
2. Это соответствует принципу минимальных привилегий, что
   положительно сказывается на безопасности. Кроме того,
   компилятор может поместить строковой литерал не только в секцию
   только для чтения, но в секцию с запретом исполнения, что может
   защитить от некоторых векторов атак.
3. Секция, помеченная как только-для-чтения может быть
   переиспользована для нескольких экземпляров одной и той же
   программы.

#### Запрет `char *s = "..."` в C++11

В языке C++ строковые литералы имеют тип `const char [N]`. До C++11
мы могли неявно пребразовать строковой литерал в тип `char *` для
совместимости с языком C, в котором строковые литералы имеют тип
`char [N]`.

Начиная с C++11 такое неявное преобразование признано устаревшим.
Это призвано помочь избежать ошибок изменения строкового литерала
(что является неопределенными поведением):

```cpp
char *s = "xtring"; // В C и C++ до C++11 является валидной
                    // строкой, в C++11, начиная с C++11 — запрещено.
s[0] = 's'; // Неопределенное поведение и в C, и в C++, вызыванное
            // изменением строкового литерала.
```

В языке C строковой литерал имеет тип `char [N]`, так как в ранних
версиях языка не было ключевого слова `const` и запрет на
изменение строкого литерал до сих пор явно указан в стандарте.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос похожий на
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760041/how-long-does-a-string-constant-live-in-c

Вкратце от туда (цитаты из стандарта - https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> Строковый литерал имеет статическую продолжительность хранения и
> длится всю жизнь программы.
>
> Все переменные, которые не имеют динамической продолжительности
> хранения, не имеют продолжительности хранения потока и не являются
> локальными, имеют статическую продолжительность хранения. Память для
> этих сущностей должна длиться в течение всей программы.

Вот тут можно посмотреть конкретно где хранятся ваши строки, так же их может оптимизировать компилятор:
https://godbolt.org/z/z77E559oE

> нельзя объявить следующее (начиная с какой-то версии C++)?
>
> ```
> char *myName = "John";
> ```

У меня компилируется(x86_64 gcc 12.1 -std=c++20 -std=c++17-std=c++11 -std=c++98) с предупреждением:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
  |     char* myName = "John";*
```

Редакт:
**Наверно имелось введу это:**

C.1 C++ and ISO C [diff.iso]
1 This subclause lists the differences between C++ and ISO C, by the chapters of this document

> **Subclause 5.13.5:**
>
> Change: String literals made const.
> The type of a string literal is changed from “array of char” to “array of const char”.

> Rationale: This avoids calling an inappropriate overloaded function, which might expect to be able to modify its argument.

> Effect on original feature: Change to semantics of well-defined feature.

> Difficulty of converting: Syntactic transformation.
> The fix is to add a cast:

```
char* p = "abc"; // valid in C, invalid in C++
 void f(char*) {
 char* p = (char*)"abc"; // OK: cast added
 f(p);
 f((char*)"def"); // OK: cast added
}
```

Comment: Ну а что не так то?

Comment: @NNL993 а что должно быть не так?

Comment: Ой простите, подумал что ваш ответ - вопрос.

Comment: Автор вопроса и так знает, что строковый литерал имеет статическую продолжительность хранения. Он спрашивает, _зачем_ это было сделано.

Comment: Тут пишут что это нужно для реюза памяти но я не смог воспроизвести, поэтому не написал,  плюс ее ж всеравно надо куда то запихнуть, и чтобы не было проблем с мертвыми указателями дали им такую продолжительность жизни (но я хз это мои спекуляции поэтому и не пишу)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349025/is-a-string-literal-in-С-created-in-static-memory

Answer (score 0):

Присваивание указателю строки объявляет только переменную, занимающую 8 байт *(64 бита)*. Но буквы данной строки остаются на усмотрение компилятора.

Места памяти для данных программы несколько. В стандарте определились по-умолчанию указывать на константную строку, для оптимизации скорости выполнения программ.

Если вы хотите изменяющуюся строку, то вы сами можете назначить место, где строка будет хранится *(глобально, стеке или куче)* и пользоваться.

```
static char _global [ ] = "John" ;
char * myName = _global ;
```

или

```
char _stack [ ] = "John" ;
char * myName = _stack ;
```

или

```
char * myName = new char [ 5 ] ;
strncpy(myName,"John",5);
delete[]myName;
```

Останется только выбрать вам место.